# Не могу решить задачу на ветвление

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите понять почему мой код обрабатывает не все случаи
Задание:
Даны четыре числа a, b, c, d. Если их сумма - четное число и произведение неотрицательное, то вывести наибольшее из них, если сумма - нечетное число и произведение неотрицательное , то вывести наименьшее из них,если произведение - отрицательное число, то вывести сумму всех четных чисел.

Формат входного файла
Входной файл содержит четыре целых числа

Формат выходного файла
Выходной файл должен содержать одно целое число

Ограничения
-1000≤a,b,c,d≤1000

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");
    int sum = 0;
    std::string str;
    std::string num ="";
    std::vector<int> mas;
    getline(input,str);

    for (int i = 0;i < str.length();i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            mas.push_back(stoi(num));
            num = "";
        }
        else {
            num += str[i];
        }
    }
    mas.push_back(stoi(num));

    if ((mas[0] + mas[1] + mas[2] + mas[3]) % 2 == 0 && (mas[0] * mas[1] * mas[2] * mas[3]) >= 0) {
        output << *std::max_element(mas.begin(), mas.end());
    }
    else if (abs(mas[0] + mas[1] + mas[2] + mas[3]) % 2 == 1 && (mas[0] * mas[1] * mas[2] * mas[3]) >= 0) {
        output << *std::min_element(mas.begin(), mas.end());
    }
    else {
        for (int i :mas) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                sum += i;
            }
        }
        output << sum;
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
}
```

Comment: "Ограничения 1000≤a,b,c,d≤1000" — то есть все 4 числа равны 1000? :)

Comment: опечатка от -1000 до 1000

Comment: А где условие, что все числа записаны в одну строку? Вы читаете одну строку, потом делаете какие-то странные вещи. Почему вы не хотите прочесть просто `input >> mas[0] >> mas[1] >> mas[2] >> mas[3]` или как-то аналогично — скажем, циклом или через `copy`? У вас чтение кардинально неверное.

Comment: Значения в файле находятся в виде одной строки из четырёх чисел между которыми стоят пробелы(я обновил вопрос там есть тестовый пример)

Comment: Да ерунда у вас написана... Одно `num += str[i];` чего стоит. Вот что оно, по-вашему, делает? 
 Добавьте после чтения `for (int i :mas) std::cout << i << "  ";` и убедитесь, что ничего не работает...

Comment: не понимаю о чём вы, только что вставил этот блок кода и мне просто вывелись числа из файла "input"

Comment: num+=str[i] складывает имеющуюся строку с символом из строки файла

Comment: Произведение `a*b*c*d` не влазит в 32-битный `int` на некоторых входных данных. Нужен `long long`.

Comment: так мы же не записываем результат произведения никуда

Comment: Действительно помогло изменить тип на лонг лонг, СПАСИБО